# LDS belief about salvation in other worlds

Tags: lds, christology

From [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14646/770) answer to another question, the below was stated.

> Mormons might believe that God had other children on other worlds, but I leave that to the Mormons to exactly clarify that doctrine. In any event, they still hold a high regard for the position of Jesus in this world.

So I am curious. Do Mormons believe that there are other worlds with humans on them? If so, the more important part of this question, do they have their own Christ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not taught often as it can lead to confusion and questions that do not concern us or our salvation. But a careful reading of the scriptures and some LDS church leaders would convey that Mormons do believe that God has made and populated other worlds and that Christ is the Savior to all of God's children and truly is The Only Begotten.

[Doctrine and Covenants section 76](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76):

> 22 And now, after the many testimonies which have been given of him, this is the testimony, last of all, which we give of him: That he lives!
>
> 23 For we saw him, even on the bright hand of God; and we heard the voice bearing record that he is the Only Begotten of the Father—
>
> 24 That by him, and through him, and of him, the worlds are and were created, and the inhabitants thereof are begotten sons and daughters unto God.

Further, in the [Book of Moses, chapter 1](http://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/moses/1.33?lang=eng#):

> 31 And behold, the glory of the Lord was upon Moses, so that Moses
> stood in the presence of God, and talked with him face to face. And
> the Lord God said unto Moses: For mine own purpose have I made these
> things. Here is wisdom and it remaineth in me.
>
> 32 And by the word of my power, have I created them, which is mine
> Only Begotten Son, who is full of grace and truth.
>
> 33 And worlds without number have I created; and I also created them
> for mine own purpose; and by the Son I created them, which is mine
> Only Begotten.
>
> 34 And the first man of all men have I called Adam, which is many.
>
> 35 But only an account of this earth, and the inhabitants thereof,
> give I unto you. For behold, there are many worlds that have passed
> away by the word of my power. And there are many that now stand, and
> innumerable are they unto man; but all things are numbered unto me,
> for they are mine and I know them.

This is in harmony with the Biblical teachings in Hebrews, for instance:

**Hebrews 1**

> 1 God, who at sundry times and in divers manners spake in time past
> unto the fathers by the prophets,
>
> 2 Hath in these last days spoken unto us by his Son, whom he hath
> appointed heir of all things, by whom also he made the worlds;

**Hebrews 11**

> 3 Through faith we understand that the worlds were framed by the word
> of God, so that things which are seen were not made of things which do
> appear.