The LDS church teaches that the universe has no beginning... thus no original god creator
If this is so... how do we arrive at today? Without a starting point, time cannot begin to move forward and we would never come to exist. An eternal future is possible but an eternal past is not. There has to be an original creator. Also... are the LDS actually worshipping a created being who was once a regular man? Are other worlds without sin or do they have their own form of Jesus? Or did their man-god find another way to deal with sin and the cross isn't necessary as we would like to think?

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Welcome to the site! The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints does not teach that the universe had no beginning (some individual Latter-day Saints have speculated about this and plenty of other Latter-day Saints disagree with those speculations). Could you cite a specific source you'd like the community to respond to? Also, this post asks several different questions - it'll be more effective to focus on a single question.

some related questions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/85978/22319, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4759/22319, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4760/22319, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/14652/22319

The question lacks focus as it is trying to answer too much all at once. Also, I am certain that there will be duplication as many of these issues have already been raised in previous questions.

Growing up LDS I was taught that the most elect would get their own planet. This was only for the cream of the LDS crop. For the last 25 years or more this doctrine has really been downplayed and I'm not sure it's even taught anymore... but at one time, it was doctrine.

"An eternal future is possible but an eternal past is not." — Is that a personal belief, or is there some scientific or religious basis for it?

Orson Pratt, one of the early Mormon apostles, wrote, "We were begotten by our Father in heaven; the person of our Father in heaven was begotten on a previous heavenly world by His Father; and again, He was begotten by a still more ancient Father; and so on, from generation to generation, from one heavenly world to another still more ancient."
Mormons believe there are many worlds with many gods. These gods have children who populate their worlds and can progress toward deification.
The path toward divine exaltation is the goal of every Mormon. Lorenzo Snow, the fifth president of the LDS church, summarized Mormonism’s doctrines of God and deification with one of the most recognizable quotes from a Mormon leader: “As man is now, God once was; as God is now man may be.”
Mormonism teaches that worthy Mormon men may follow the same path as Heavenly Father (“the law of eternal progression”). They can evolve from preexistence to mortal human existence to divine exaltation. Women too may achieve celestial exaltation, becoming like Heavenly Mother, the wife of God the Father, though the LDS church admits their knowledge of Heavenly Mother is limited.
In sum, the LDS God (Heavenly Father) is an exalted man who once lived on a planet like ours. He achieved celestial exaltation, exists with a physical body in the celestial realm, has Heavenly Mother as his eternal wife, and populates our planet with his children.

In regards to Orson Pratt's opinion please see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/99514/22319

sources to your statements would improve your answer.

I also think they believe that matter is uncreated and that when Genesis talks about God creating it is not ex nihilo but a forming or reshaping of existing matter.  In this sense there would be no beginning of time since time is inseparable from matter and space.
